# What do I have wrong here?

Tags: python, array

I have this code:

```
import numpy as np 

height = [1.72, 1.78, 1.80, 1.90]
weight = [55.6, 60.7, 68.8, 70.8, 80.9]

np_height = np.array(height)
np_weight = np.array(weight)



bmi = np_weight / np_height ** 2



print(bmi)
```

And python gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "learning.py", line 11, in <module>
    bmi = np_weight / (np_height ** 2)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,) (4,)
```

Comment: Estas en Stackoverflow en español, te sugiero publicar tu pregunta en español, o ir a stackoverflow en ingles para realizar preguntas en ingles.

Answer (score 1):

Las longitudes de height y weight son distintas. Si usas listas con el mismo número de elementos, va OK!

The length of height and weight are different. Using the same length for both lists, the program runs OK!

Run this:

```
import numpy as np

height = [1.72, 1.78, 1.80, 1.90, 2.0]
weight = [55.6, 60.7, 68.8, 70.8, 80.9]

np_height = np.array(height)
np_weight = np.array(weight)

bmi = np_weight / np_height ** 2

print(bmi)
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a la comunidad. Es maravilloso que quieras aportar pero evitamos responder a preguntas de baja calidad o en un idioma diferente al español ya que pueden terminar cerradas. En su lugar, orientamos al OP para que traduzca su pregunta y luego procedemos a responder. Te invito a hacer [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que sepas de lo que hablo.

Comment: Entendido. Intentaré cumplirlo, pero el ánimo de ayudar me ha podido. Si quieres, la elimino.

Comment: calma colega @kalma... creo que no es necesario ;). Si el OP traduce su pregunta, tu respuesta puede ser útil, si no lo hace, simplemente su pregunta será eliminada, _ya tiene varios votos negativos_. Solo te dejé el comentario para que lo tengas en cuenta, también para que ganes reputación y medallas al hacer el recorrido.